how to reupload a file to GitHub from VS Code after deleting it from GitHub
i have deleted some file from github repository now i want reupload these files from vs code in that repository how to reupload these files .
i am cheching the status of that project from vs code it showing  "On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Why did you delete them??

So normally ensure that the status is recognizing the deleted files..
with:

git status

and then u should see the deleted files !
either add them one by one with :

git add  < file2>

or easily you can add all again with

git add .

Commit and push and it'll be fine !

git status is not recognizing the deleted files . git status is On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean

then try this to force rescan  : git fetch origin ,git add -A ,git status
